POST Request to /api/auth/register Returns 404 Error in React App - Backend Endpoint Not Found
I'm working on a React frontend that communicates with an Express.js backend. When I attempt to register a user by making a POST request to /api/auth/register, I'm getting a 404 error, with the response indicating "Cannot POST /api/auth/register". Below is my frontend code and the error details.
Frontend Code (React):
import React, { useState } from "react";
import api from "../services/api";

const Register: React.FC = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const validateEmail = (email: string) => {
    const re = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
    return re.test(email);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      setError("Passwords do not match");
      return;
    }
    if (!validateEmail(email)) {
      setError("Invalid email format");
      return;
    }
    try {
      await api.post("/auth/register", { name, email, password });
      alert("Registration successful");
      setError("");
    } catch (error) {
      setError("Error registering user");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="max-w-lg mx-auto mt-10 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-6 text-center">Register</h1>
      {error && <p className="text-red-500 mb-4 text-center">{error}</p>}
      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        className="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4"
      >
        <div className="mb-6">
          <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
            Name
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-6">
          <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
            Email
          </label>
          <input
            type="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-6">
          <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
            Password
          </label>
          <input
            type="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-6">
          <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
            Confirm Password
          </label>
          <input
            type="password"
            value={confirmPassword}
            onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
            className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            required
          />
        </div>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="w-full bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
        >
          Register
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;

Console Error:
POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register 404 (Not Found)

Response:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /api/auth/register</pre>
</body>
</html>

Backend Setup:
In my Express.js backend, I have defined the following routes:
import express from 'express';
import { registerUser } from '../controllers/authController';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/register', registerUser);

export default router;

And in app.ts:
import authRoutes from './routes/authRoutes';

app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);

What I've Checked So Far:

The backend server is running.
The /api/auth/register route is correctly set up in the backend.
I've confirmed that the frontend is making a POST request to the correct URL.

Despite this, I'm still getting the 404 error. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Have you tried sending a POST request using an API tool such as Insomnia or Postman? If so, was that successful?
